# C++: I don't know how to solve the timeout in the problem of comparing coordinates in the coordinate plane

Tags: c++, algorithm, coordinates

Up to 100,000 coordinates are entered. Only coordinates corresponding to specific conditions should be output. If there are coordinates with larger x values ​​and smaller y values ​​than each coordinate, the corresponding coordinates are excluded from the output list.

My English is not good, so I'm giving some examples.

**[input]** First enter the number of coordinates N to be input. and enter the coordinates.

**[output]** The coordinate numbers corresponding to the condition are output in ascending order.

[p2 is not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro3Q2.png)
[p4 is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqLPr.png)

```
[input example]

6
1 3
6 6
7 3
8 2
8 6
2 1
```

```
[output example]

4
5
6
```

**The time limit is 500ms.**

```
[timeout input example]

50000
1 1
1 2
1 3
... skip
1 49999
1 50000
```

```
[timeout output example]

1 1
1 2
1 3
... skip
1 49999
1 50000
```

coordinates image:

[image: img]

The following problem was solved with a simple loop, but a timeout occurs when 100,000 values ​​are entered. I don't know which algorithm to use.

I also attach the C++ source code I wrote.

Also, I tried using the sort function, but when the number of N is small, it works fine, and when the number of N is large, it cannot be compared properly. I guess I couldn't write the compare function properly.
So I tried writing the source code without using sort.

I thought and corrected it over two days, but I couldn't solve it, so I seek help. thanks for reading.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    bool* visible = new bool[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)visible[i] = true;
    
    vector<pair<int,pair<int, int>>> v;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        v.push_back(make_pair(i,make_pair(a, b)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (visible[i] == false)
            continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++) {
            if (visible[i] == true &&visible[j]==true && v[i].second.first < v[j].second.first && v[i].second.second > v[j].second.second) {
                visible[i] = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (visible[i] == true && visible[j] == true && v[i].second.first > v[j].second.first && v[i].second.second < v[j].second.second) {
                visible[j] = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (visible[i] == true)
            cout << v[i].first + 1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**[Source code that tried to sort but failed]**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
bool* visible;

int compare(pair<int, pair<int, int>> n1, pair<int, pair<int, int>> n2) {
    pair<int, int> a = n1.second, b = n2.second;
    bool swap = false;
    if (a.first > b.first && a.second < b.second) { 
        visible[n2.first - 1] = false;
        swap = true;
    }
    else if (a.first < b.first && a.second > b.second) {
        visible[n1.first - 1] = false;
        //swap = true;
    }

    cout << "[" << n1.first << "]" << a.first << ", " << a.second << " vb : " << visible[n1.first - 1] << " :\t[" << n2.first << "]" << b.first << ", " << b.second << "vb : " << visible[n2.first - 1] << "\t";
    cout << "swap: " << swap << endl;
    return swap;
}
int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    visible = new bool[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)visible[i] = true;
    vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        v.push_back(make_pair(i+1, make_pair(a, b)));
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        cout << "p" << v[i].first << " : " << v[i].second.first << ", " << v[i].second.second <<"\t"<< visible[v[i].first-1]<< endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

In this case, p4 moves to (4,2). In this case, p3,4,5,6 becomes the correct answer.

Comment: Where does this timeout come from? There's nothing in your code that could trigger such behavior.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ 
I can't put 50,000 inputs here

Comment: 50000
1 1
1 2
1 3
...
1 49999
1 50000

Comment: Some kind of sorting seems the way to go. Since you tried that (and failed) then that is the code you should be posting here. Not this code. For some reason people don't want to post non-working code, but that's exactly the code we need to see if we are going to help.

Comment: @CODe5753 It may take some time to read these in and compare, but there's no intrinsic c++ mechanism which would _timeout_ a program which is taking too long to to do tthat. You can even program an endless loop, and it will simply run endless. Hence the question: From where does this timeout come from?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ From a competition site, and since the OP seems fairly deparate I would guess they are a student and this is homework. I've only recently realized that this is what competition sites are being used for in some places.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I believe he's coding on an online practice site, and they often have a timer for how long the code would run. If it exceeds that time, it will say timeout, where you basically failed to answer the question in an expected way.

Comment: @john 
I attached my final source code and the simple test case passed. However, looking at the timeout example, it was not passing, but I did not know what algorithm to use to solve this problem, so I asked.

Comment: @john 
This is a problem I brought directly from the github open source oj site, and you can attach a photo of evidence.

Comment: It's not an assignment, it's for self-study. It works as a docker on my workstation, and it is also uploaded to github.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yes, we can suspect that, but that has nothing to do with errors in that code. We cannot know what the requirements and restrictions of that site are, but this would be essential information needed to solve the problem.

Comment: "I tried using the sort function" Where? We can't see that.

Comment: Please explain exactly why the output is `4 5 6`.  I cannot rationalize how this relates to _"If there are coordinates with larger x values AND smaller y values ​​than EACH coordinate, the corresponding coordinates are excluded from the output list"_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ One can pretty much assume that the restriction is "don't use an obvious dumb O(n^2) algorithm, we will make sure it doesn't meet the time requirement".

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Assumptions and guessing isn't a useful approach for questions here. Such questions will be useless for future researchers tackling similar problems.

Comment: The source code that used the sort function was added. And I will write an additional explanation to the problem. thank you for helping.

Comment: @CODe5753 Try optimising the nested loops in a way you don't visit points you already had tested before, you'll need some extra datastructure to remember these, e.g. a map with points as key and bool as value.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ 
In the first code I wrote, the nesting was minimized with visible variables.

Comment: Added two photos. This is not correct because there are other coordinates in the range where x is larger than p2 and y is smaller. On the other hand, in the case of p4,5,6, the answer is correct because there is no coordinate in each range.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You cannot move an inch without assuming a thousand different things. This particular assumption is reasonable based on my experience with these competition sites.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I inserted the code that tried to sort, and I asked the question because I couldn't solve it even if I thought about it alone.

Comment: Well obviously the code that tries to sort doesn't attempt to output in the right format and skip the invisible points. Why would you expect it to work?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The code that worked properly went through a lot of modifications. That source code is invalid because this process is not left. I know my final code is O(N^2), so I'm wondering what algorithm I should use to save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure this works for every corner case, but the idea is here. It took me a while to nail it down, probably because the problem description wasn't exactly clear. Basically you want to mark as *not visible* the points for which it is possible to find another one with a larger x and a smaller y, i.e. the points which have another on their lower right.

If you sort your points on x, then you only need to check those with a larger index.

In fact, we are interested only in the one with the minimum y, because it will dominate all others.

That value can only decrease while moving from right to left, so we just need to keep track of the minimum y. The only problem is how to deal with points that have the same x, because they could have a lower y before a higher one, rendering valid points *non visible*. The trick is to make sure that when browsed from right to left (higher indices to lower ones) the y will decrease. So when sorting, if x is equal we will sort on y.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    struct point {
        int x, y;
        bool visible = true;
    };

    size_t N;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::vector<point> v(N);
    std::vector<size_t> idx(N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        auto& p = v[i];
        idx[i] = i;
        std::cin >> p.x >> p.y;
    }

    sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(), [&v](const size_t& a, const size_t& b) { 
        if (v[a].x == v[b].x)
            return v[a].y < v[b].y;
        return v[a].x < v[b].x; 
    });

    int miny = INT_MAX;
    for (size_t i = N; i-- > 0;) {
        auto& p = v[idx[i]];
        miny = std::min(miny, p.y);
        if (p.y > miny) {
            p.visible = false;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        auto& p = v[i];
        if (p.visible) {
            std::cout << i + 1 << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood two things from your code, so I'll list both the solutions:

I: This is a basic example of a modified 'Longest Increasing Subsequence'.

Let's first consider the coordinates as something different, let's say , the coordinate (x,y), would become the ractangle with height (x) and width (y) (consider this as if we were making rectangles with corners (0,0) (x,0) (0,y) (x,y)).

If we need 'ascending' points, it means that their areas overlap. More formally, if the list of point we need is A(1),A(2),A(3),...,A(k), then for each i in range 1..k-1,  A(i).x<A(i+1).x and A(i).y<A(i+1).y.

You can find an optimal solution using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/)

Note: the coordinates should be sorted. By what criteria? Well, as long as the longest increasing subsequence would appear after a sorting of that criteria, then it's correct.

II: This is a basic example of finding the convex hull.

The convex hull of a polygon would be the convex polygon (with the most nodes) , whose set of coordinates is included in the set of the coordinates of the original polygon. I recommend reading [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) . After finding the upper half, you can apply a mentality as described in the previous example, although you must find a substring instead of a subsequence, so that would make the complexity O(nlog+n)

Hope this was helpful

Comment: I'm not quite sure what longest increasing anything has to do with this. Points don't have to come in any particular order, so there might be no increasing subsequences at all. Convex hull seems right.

Comment: No, sorry, convex hull isn't right either. Consider e.g. points ((0,0), (1,2), (3,3), (1,4)). (1,2) is not in the convex hull but it is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Given two points A and B, there are three possible configurations:

1. A makes B invisible
2. B makes A invisible
3. None of the above

The "makes-invisible" relation between the points is not [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) required by `std::sort`, so calling `std::sort` with a comparison function that implements this relation is undefined.